# ErrorException proc_open(): fork failed - Resource temporarily unavailable'

Tags: laravel, exception, cron, server, queue

Guys I am using Linux server to host my Laravel application. My application uses Laravel job scheduler and queue for handling background processes like fetching emails and sending system generated emails. When I try to listen the queued jobs for background processes on my local machine, it works fine. But on live server it is failing to process the jobs.
I've set up a cron job on a server which runs the artisan command to listen queue.
[image]

here's the function which runs queue listen command

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    if (env('DB_INSTALL') == 1) {
        $queue = $this->getCurrentQueue();
        $schedule->command('queue:listen '.$queue, ['--tries' => 1])->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
        $this->execute($schedule, 'fetching');
        $this->execute($schedule, 'notification');
        $this->execute($schedule, 'work');
        $this->execute($schedule, 'followup');
        $this->execute($schedule, 'message');
        loging('cron', 'executed successfully','info');
    }
}
```

In my log file it is logging that the cron has been executed successfully but it's not processing background mails. Some time it shows the Error Exception

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this error. TIA

Comment: I've searched in various forums and all conclude that the problem is occurring due to low server memory(RAM).  
http://i.stack.imgur.com/410pQ.png
The server I am using is a shared server and more than 5 cron jobs were running on the server at the time. I removed all other crons and now it works fine. But I am still not sure about it.